# XMLUnit - Issue comparing to XMLs that are not in same order

Tags: java, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I am using XMLUnit2 to compare 2 XMLs which don't have elements in the same order. I am seeing the below error -

> Differences = Expected child 'billingCode' but was 'null' - comparing
>    at
>   /translateServiceRequestResponse[1]/translateServiceRequestReturn[1]/legacyCode[2]/billingCode[1] to NULL

**Code**

```
Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(controlResponse).ignoreWhitespace().ignoreComments().withTest(testResponse).withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)).checkForSimilar().build();
System.out.println("Differences = " + myDiff.toString());
```

**Control File**

```
<translateServiceRequestResponse>
<translateServiceRequestReturn>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VS128</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>0</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VF123</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <packageCode>VE286</packageCode>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>0</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VF170</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <packageCode>VE286</packageCode>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>2.5</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
</translateServiceRequestReturn>
```

**Test File**

```
<translateServiceRequestResponse>
<translateServiceRequestReturn>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VS128</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>0</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VF170</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <packageCode>VE286</packageCode>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>2.5</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
    <legacyCode>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <billingCode>VF123</billingCode>
        <description>HD Rec</description>
        <packageCode>VE286</packageCode>
        <priceName>EquipChoice X1 HD TP</priceName>
        <pricingElementName>X1 HD Receiver</pricingElementName>
        <codeAmount>0</codeAmount>
        <lobSubType>0</lobSubType>
        <addressable>1</addressable>
        <nonStandard>false</nonStandard>
    </legacyCode>
</translateServiceRequestReturn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLUnit uses the `ElementSelector` in order to determine which elements of two sets of siblings in the control and test documents to match with each other. It will start matching from the root of the documents and you must ensure it picks the correct branches at each level. Once a decision has been made, XMLUnit won't back-track.

When picking an `ElementSelector` you must always ensure it helps XMLUnit to take the correct branch as close to the root of the document as the logical structure of your document requires. The elements you say are not in the same order are the `legacyCode` elements, so you must help XMLUnit to make the correct selection among them. `byNameAndText` won't help here. There is no nested text in `byNameAndText` at all, so they are all the same and XMLUnit matches the elements in document order.

This is exactly the same problem as the one about `tr`s in https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes

To me looks as if your `legacyCode` would be identified by the text nested into the `billingCode` element. If so you could use an `ElementSelector` like

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("legacyCode").thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./billingCode", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

You may need to adapt this so it works for parts of the of the document you haven't shown or if `byNameAndText` really is required rather than `byName` for some other parts of the tree.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. I have a number of elements similar to legacyCode listed here. Should I specify each of them by name or is there a generic way to formulate this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Next to `whenElementIsNamed` there also is `when` which accepts a `Predicate<Node>`. If there's a rule you can specify that selects all your elements, you could use that.

Comment: Thanks again , Stephan. Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: Depends on what your elements have in common. Assuming you've got a set of element names `NAMES` and could do something like `ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder().when(e -> NAMES.contains(Nodes.getQName(e).getLocalPart())).thenUse(...)`. If it is always a different child element to look for, then you'll likely have to spell out all elements and children explicitly.